# Paginate on WordPress Archive for Custom Post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type in WordPress and on the archive page, I want to add pagination.

I have the following code, but when I click on page 2 or 'next', it reloads page 1.

My first thought was it should be added before `wp_reset_postdata()`. But that displayed the links alongside every post.

What am I missing, please?

```php
<!-- custom query for village life posts -->
<?php

$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$args               = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'post_type'      => 'villagelife',
    'orderby'        => 'post_date',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'paged'          => $paged,
);
$villagelifeArchive = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $villagelifeArchive->have_posts() ) {
    $villagelifeArchive->the_post();
    ?>

    <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="grid-item-wrapper">
            <div class="grid-item-container">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                <div class="grid-image-top">
                    <span class="centered project-image-bg"><a title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'archive-village-life-image' ); ?></a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="grid-item-content">
                <span class="item-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>
                <span class="item-category"><?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'village-life-category', '', ', ', ' ' ); ?></span>
                <span class="item-excerpt"><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 18 ); ?></span>
                <?php echo '<a class="button ast-button more-info" href=' . get_the_permalink() . '>Read More..</a>'; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
wp_reset_postdata();

$total_pages = $villagelifeArchive->max_num_pages;
print_r( $total_pages );// give me 2 ..the correct answer.

if ( $total_pages > 1 ) {
    $current_page = max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) );
    ?>
    <div>
    <?php
    echo paginate_links(
        array(
            'base'    => get_pagenum_link( 1 ) . '%_%',
            'format'  => '/page/%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total'   => $total_pages,
        )
    );
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently unable to help with your issue, but I have got the php I use for pagination.

Add the below to your functions.php file

```php
<?php
function og_pagination() {
    global $wp_query;

    $big = 999999999;

    $links = paginate_links(
        array(
            'base'      => str_replace( $big, '%#%', html_entity_decode( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'current'   => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
            'total'     => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
            'mid_size'  => 5,
            'prev_next' => true,
            'prev_text' => '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" height="14px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" fill="#000000"><path d="M9.7,18.3L9.7,18.3c0.39-0.39,0.39-1.02,0-1.41L5.83,13H21c0.55,0,1-0.45,1-1v0c0-0.55-0.45-1-1-1H5.83l3.88-3.88 c0.39-0.39,0.39-1.02,0-1.41l0,0c-0.39-0.39-1.02-0.39-1.41,0L2.7,11.3c-0.39,0.39-0.39,1.02,0,1.41l5.59,5.59 C8.68,18.68,9.32,18.68,9.7,18.3z"/></svg>',
            'next_text' => '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" height="14px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" fill="#000000"><path d="M14.29,5.71L14.29,5.71c-0.39,0.39-0.39,1.02,0,1.41L18.17,11H3c-0.55,0-1,0.45-1,1v0c0,0.55,0.45,1,1,1h15.18l-3.88,3.88 c-0.39,0.39-0.39,1.02,0,1.41l0,0c0.39,0.39,1.02,0.39,1.41,0l5.59-5.59c0.39-0.39,0.39-1.02,0-1.41L15.7,5.71 C15.32,5.32,14.68,5.32,14.29,5.71z"/></svg>',
            'type'      => 'array',
        )
    );

    if ( $links ) {
        echo '<div class="pagination">';
        echo '<ul>';

        foreach ( $links as $link ) {
            printf( '<li>%s</li>', str_replace( '/page/1', '', $link ) );
        }

        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Are you calling this function in your template file where you have the loop?

Comment: *I am currently unable to help with your issue*- what does that mean? Did your answer resolve the issue or not?

Comment: Hi, problem isn't resolve yet

Comment: Hi John, Sorry for the delay, if you put this in your function.php file. Then call <?php og_pagination(); ?> outside the loop. Hopefully this works for you :)